# Getting gridpanel's cell value. ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid panel with some columns and `CheckboxSelectionModel`. When i check sone rows i want to get a value of the `id` cell.

[image]

```
var sm = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({

    listeners: {
        selectionchange: function(sm) {
        alert('coucou : ' + sm.getSelected().id);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok im dummy. To get a value of cell with name `id` needed

```
var sm = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({

      listeners: {
       selectionchange: function(sm) {
       alert('coucou : ' + sm.getSelected().get("id"));
      }
    }
});
```